# Firebase - Phone number verification

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm building a simple app and I want to have phone number auth. However, after following the instructions on the site, nothing seems to be firing.

```
// App.js

handleNext = () => {
    verifyPhoneNumber(this.state.phoneNumber);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1
    }));
  };
...
<Button
         size="small"
         onClick={this.handleNext}
         disabled={activeStep === maxSteps - 1}
         id={"verify-phone-number-button"}
         >
         Next
</Button>

//Controller.js
export const verifyPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) => {
  console.log(phoneNumber) // +14084445555
  firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('verify-phone-number-button', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': function (response) {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      console.log("reCAPTCHA solved")
      var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
      firebaseApp.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (confirmationResult) {
          // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
          // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
          window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
          console.log("success")
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
          // Error; SMS not sent
          // ...
        });
    }
  });
}
```

`reCAPTCHA solved` never gets printed meaning it never makes it there. However, it also isn't printing any error messages so I'm unsure of what is happening.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the `handleNext` function your button is bound to do?

Comment: @Phix I've added `handleNext` in my code block. Hope this helps